# Codeigniter 3.0 captcha 404

Tags: php, codeigniter, continuous-integration, captcha

I have problem with helper captcha in codeigniter (3.0).
Captcha work good but in logs is:

```
ERROR - 2016-09-22 08:32:25 --> 404 Page Not Found: [207.46.XXX.XXX] > /upload/captcha/1470072358.0468.jpg
```

and every day is ~100 errors.

Where is problem?

My controller:

```
$random_number = substr(number_format(time() * rand(), 0, '', ''), 0, 6);
        // setting up captcha config
        $vals = array(
            'word'       => $random_number,
            'img_path'   => './upload/captcha/',
            'img_url'    => base_url() . 'upload/captcha/',
            'img_width'  => 140,
            'img_height' => 32,
            'expiration' => 7200,
            'pool'       => '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
            'colors'     => array(
                'background' => array(255, 255, 255),
                'border'     => array(255, 255, 255),
                'text'       => array(111, 34, 45),
                'grid'       => array(255, 40, 40),
            ),
            'font_path'  => base_url() . 'system/fonts/texb.ttf',
        );
        $data            = array();
        $data['captcha'] = create_captcha($vals);
        $this->session->set_userdata('captchaWord', $data['captcha']['word']);
        $this->view_data['captcha'] = create_captcha($vals);
```

Comment: do you have the upload folder.. you can change the image_path as `FCPATH.'upload/captcha/'` like this

Comment: I try and is to same...

Answer (score 0):

A program that use for human verification or program which protect websites against bots, spam etc.
Generally Captcha contain a image for human challenge on forms for human read and enter captcha image text. In codeigniter we can easily add captcha to website using captcha helper class. it’s provided by codeigniter default. In this article how to use captcha in codeigniter We are using session and a callback function to validate a captcha field/words. There is also alternate you can also manage captcha with database but using session is a simple way to manage. Below i am sharing an example how to use captcha in codeigniter website forms.

1. create a directory on root with named “captcha”(must be writable).
2. create a controller with named “captcha. php” under “application/controllers/”
3. create a view file with named “captcha.php” under “application/views/” and add below code.

Comment: I'm not sure you are answering his question.